# Parsing a JSON string with multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to parse this JSON string

```
$json = {"fields":{
"relationshipStatus":[{"fieldId":4,"name":"Committed"},{"fieldId":2,"name":"Dating"},{"fieldId":6,"name":"Engaged"},{"fieldId":3,"name":"Exclusive"},{"fieldId":7,"name":"Married"},{"fieldId":8,"name":"Open Relationship"},{"fieldId":5,"name":"Partnered"},{"fieldId":1,"name":"Single"}],
            "ethnicity":[{"fieldId":1,"name":"Asian"},{"fieldId":2,"name":"Black"},{"fieldId":3,"name":"Latino"},{"fieldId":4,"name":"Middle Eastern"},{"fieldId":5,"name":"Mixed"},{"fieldId":6,"name":"Native American"},{"fieldId":8,"name":"Other"},{"fieldId":9,"name":"South Asian"},{"fieldId":7,"name":"White"}],
}}
```

Using this foreach loop, ultimately I want to be able to take the data and use them as Select / List dropdowns on a form.

```
foreach($json['fields'] as $item){
    foreach($item['relationshipStatus'] as $relationship){
        echo $relationship['name'] . " " . $relationship['fieldId'] . "<br/>";
    }

    foreach($item['ethnicity'] as $ethnicity){
        echo $ethnicity['name'] . " " . $ethnicity['fieldId'] . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

No matter how I try to pull the data out, I keep getting errors similar to:

> Notice: Undefined index: relationshipStatus in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/updateprofile.php on line 126 Warning:
>   Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/updateprofile.php on line 126

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you pretty-print the json (ie using jsonlint.com) you'll see that the array is actually under `$json['fields']['relationshipStatus']`, and not directly under `$json['fields']` as in your code.

Comment: You're absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1):

The first foreach selects already `relationshipStatus` and `ethnicity`. Maybe the following changes show what I mean:

```
foreach($json['fields'] as $key=>$item){
if ($key == 'relationshipStatus')
foreach($item as $relationship){
    echo $relationship['name'] . " " . $relationship['fieldId'] . "<br/>";
}
else if ($key == 'ethnicity')
foreach($item as $ethnicity){
    echo $ethnicity['name'] . " " . $ethnicity['fieldId'] . "<br/>";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you iterating the `JSON Object` in a wrong way.The array values you want to fetch is actually under `$json['fields']['relationshipStatus']`.

```
var name = $json['fields']['relationshipStatus']['name'];
var fieldId = $json['fields']['relationshipStatus']['fieldId'];
```

=============================== OR ========================================

As described by the **`A.fink`**

```
foreach($json['fields'] as $key=>$item){
if ($key == 'relationshipStatus')
foreach($item as $relationship){
    echo $relationship['name'] . " " . $relationship['fieldId'] . "<br/>";
}
else if ($key == 'ethnicity')
foreach($item as $ethnicity){
    echo $ethnicity['name'] . " " . $ethnicity['fieldId'] . "<br/>";
}
}
```